# Using Confluence as a development environment sandbox

Tags: javascript, css, confluence

Is it possible to use Confluence to provide a collaborative place to develop front end code (CSS/JS) using a sandbox for example for real time examples?

For example, if Developer X creates a useful jQuery plugin, they could in theory create a page showing a working example, the source used to create the example, any documentation, etc.  I see this as a great way to create a showcase of work across our company which can then be auto-packaged into a 'framework'.

Comment: Confluence could be used for this, yes.

Comment: Is it 'out of the box' or will it require significant work to implement?

Comment: You should be able to do what you're describing without any extra add-ons. It's pretty easy to create pages which have a variety of content on them, so you could have an example of some jQuery and then show the source and any other description or documentation needed.